# How to pass an HttpContext object from a controller to a repository class in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

I have a repository class with a constructor which accepts an `HttpContext` object as its parameter. How can I pass a `HttpContext` object from a controller to this repository class in my MVC project?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the current HttpContext in a controller action, you can do this:

```
public ActionResult Action(...) {
    var repository = new MyRepository(this.HttpContext) ;
    ...
}
```

Although I have to add, this sounds like problematic design. I can't think of any reason why a repository class would need the context directly. If I needed data from my context to go into my model, I would create a value object (aka data transfer object), serialize the HttpContext as required and pass that into the repository.